# How to say 'NO', When someone offer you better opportunity with better salary?

Tags: professionalism, communication, job-offer, career-development

I am a professional Magento Developer, and I have completed my one year and continue my next one year bond.

When someone offers you a better opportunity with a better salary but you have to continue with your older company than how can I say

> "No, I am comfortable with my company and in future when I want to
>   change then I will inform you"

in a better way.

So, How can I politely decline a new job offers?

Comment: What do you think is impolite about that?

Comment: Would you have accepted the offer if there were no bond, just a normal, for your industry and location, notice period?

Answer (score 21):

That’s not what you want to say. You want to tell them that you would be happy to accept their offer but can’t at the moment because of the bond.

The new company may decide to do something to get you released earlier if they want to, so your problem goes away. Or they may hold on that information and contact you in a year.

If you say you’re comfortable where you are, they will not be interested in you at all. Your chances of getting any job with them in the future won’t be good.

Comment: ^ Exactly. No point in lying and making it sound like you're not interested if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Just say

> *"No, I am comfortable with my company and in future when I want to change then I will inform you"*

in a little more *polished* version

> *"Thanks for the offer, but right now I'm not looking for a change. I'll get back to you if I change my mind."*

Comment: I like the edit.  The original statement reads a little like (yes, I'm exaggerating), "If you're ever good enough, maybe you'll be lucky enough to hear from me.  Until then, stop pestering me."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your rejection as you have currently phrased it. I often get offers and reply in a similar way:

> [Thanks for your interest/Thanks for reaching out], but I'm not looking for a new position at this time. I'll be sure to reach out to you if anything changes.

I have never had anyone take that badly